# java string format method

Tags: java, string-formatting

What I want to do is getting the first 2 digits of a number. If number hasn't digits more than 1 then It will add leading zeros.

s variable equals to "122" but I want to get first 2 digits which are "12". I think there is a problem with my format.

for example if totalNumberOfCars equals 6 then s variable will equals to "06".

```
int totalNumberOfCars = 122;
String s = String.format("%02d", (totalNumberOfCars + 1))
```

**EDIT:** Is there anyone knows what String.format("%02d", totalNumberOfCars) does?

Comment: why are you writing this one : (totalNumberOfCars + 1)?

Comment: @codeMan I edited. It is not important actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that `String.format()` won't do the job, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax.

But your format string will be a good starting point for a substring since any ifs are unnecessary:

```
int totalNumberOfCars = 122;
String s = String.format("%02d", (totalNumberOfCars + 1));
s = s.substring(0,2);
```

By the way the condensed explaination from the javadoc link above:

> The format specifiers which do not correspond to arguments have the following syntax:
>
> ```
>   %[flags][width]conversion
> ```

[...] further down on the same page:

> Flags 
>   '0' [...] [means] zero-padded

[...] further down on the same page:

> Width
>
> The width is the minimum number of characters to be written to the output. For the line separator conversion, width is not applicable; if it is provided, an exception will be thrown.

Example output would be:

```
1  --> 01
-1 --> -1
10 --> 10
122--> 122
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not very elegant, but it should work:

```
String s = ((totalNumberOfCars<10?"0":"")+totalNumberOfCars).substring(0,2);
```

Answer (score -1):

String s = substring_safe (s, 0, 2);

static String substring_safe (String s, int start, int len) { ... }
which will check lengths beforehand and act accordingly (either return smaller string or pad with spaces).